# Как правильно загрузить изображение во внутреннюю память устройства в созданную папку и получить к изображению путь?

Tags: java, android

Это необходимо для SQLite.
Саму папку, куда должны скачиваться изображения, создала. Путь к папке получить могу. Но главная проблема в скачивании самого изображения. Picasso и Glide работают через Bitmap, хочется более прямого скачивания, без конвертирования.

Как правильно загрузить изображение во внутреннюю память устройства в созданную папку и получить к изображению путь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте AsyncTask, в doInBackGround опишите процесс скачивания и записи файла в нужное место, запустите этот AsyncTask там, где нужно, передав в него адрес файла, который нужно скачать.

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Try to download file");
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);
            // Сохранение во внутреннюю защищенную память, при необходимости изменить
            FileOutputStream output = openFileOutput(IMAGE_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Finish downloading file");

        return null;
    }
}
```

И запустите его в нужном месте кода

```
new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(FILE_URL);
```

Comment: А всегда запись изображений во внутреннюю папку устройства происходит через `byte[]`? Нельзя получить через Glide значение `Drawable resource` и записать именно drawable во внутреннюю папку устройства?

Comment: Вы хотели более прямого скачивания, вот вам побайтовое скачивание - получите, распишитесь)))) Насчет Glide чуть позже напишу, если никто вперед не ответит.

Comment: Спасибо вам за приведенный пример. Видимо я не так немного выразилась. Если по простому, то хотелось бы, чтобы изображение можно было бы скачать без всяких конвертирований (без байтов, bitmap и подобного), просто изображение. Честно, как раз Glide, на мой взгляд, будет то что нужно.

Comment: а как получить изображение исходя из вашего кода?